# Parent node not accessible during Controller object's initialize() method but ok when accessed later on

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I am currently quite puzzled by the behaviour of JavaFX with regards to nested FXMLs and associated Controllers and would greatly appreciate your help on this one;

**This is how the code is structured:**

1. Stage
2. --> Scene loaded from "Main" FXML with BorderPane as root Node and AnchorPane as 'center' Node
3. ----> in center-AnchorPane, <fx:include> of nested "Login" FXML file (with VBox as top-Node and including a "Login" button)
4. ------> Login controller, injected with top-Node of Login FXML file (a VBox in the Login FXML)

**Then in the controller, here is what happens from my understanding:**

- Construction (nothing there)
- FXML injection
- initialize()
- **NOTHING?**
- event-driven method on login button-click

**What I am trying to do:**

Accessing the Login FXML's top-Node's Parent from the Login's FXML Controller via: injected_topNode_Login_VBox.getParent().blahblahblah

**What doesn't work:**

- *During the Login FXML nested controller's initialize() method*, executing the above statement returns 'null'.
- *During the Login FXML nested controller's initialize() method*, accessing the same Parent node, but from the top-down (I have a Scene-Handling class from which I can fetch the VBox's Parent node). The interesting part here is that at that time - even though it is accessed in a static way via SceneHandlerClassName.getRootNode() where getRootNode() is a static method - the Root Node element (of the outter FXML) is also returned as being 'null'..

**What works:**

- *During the Login FXML nested controller's event-driven method loginButtonClick()*, executing the exact same statement returns the AnchorPane from the Main FXML scene, as expected.

**In short:**

- Construction
- FXML injection
- initialize()        --> Parent of Login VBox **not reachable** through VBox.getParent()
- **NOTHING?**
- event-driven method --> Parent of Login VBox **reachable** through VBox.getParent()

From my understanding, all properties should already  be available at the initialize() method's runtime execution, and I don't see why getParent() would return null then...
Has someone got an answer for me, please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :) :)
Cheers,

Peter

**PS:** I did not enclose the original code as it is quite simple in nature really, and I think my problem is most probably about my conception of how JavaFX's initialize() method is working.

**Edit1:** Ok, I have a new finding after @Slaw 's comment:
I have tried, still in the initialize() method of the child FXML's controller, to access the parent of the top-level node in a different way (now documented in "What doesn't work").

Comment: All fields injected by FXML _are_ available when `initialize()` is invoked. But it sounds like `injected_topNode_Login_VBox` is the root of this nested FXML file and you're trying to access its _parent_ (something not managed by the nested FXML file). So what's likely happening, assuming I understand the chain of events correctly and you've done everything else right, is that the nested FXML file gets loaded and fully initialized before the outer FXML file is. Hence your `VBox` has not been added to a parent yet.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @Slaw 
Hi and thank you for your answer.
I think you have understood the chain of events correctly indeed.
Only point I need to clarify:
The outter FXML is loaded first, then only the inner FXML gets loaded (I know this for sure, as I am switching this inner FXML depending on context).

Could you please suggest how to still access the parent (from the outter FXML) at init-time?
Cheers.

Comment: @Slaw 
I just edited the post with a new finding. Would you mind having a look please?

Comment: One option is to get the nested controller (you can inject the nested controller into the outer controller) and simply pass the parent to it via a method call. Or you can, in the nested controller, add a listener to the `parent` property of the root of the FXML and react when it becomes non-null. However, I don't think you'll be able to get the parent from the nested controller's `initialize` method. My guess is the nested FXML is not added to its parent until afterwards.

Comment: @Slaw
Yes, I think that you are right about the initialize method's behaviour. Strange to me that I can't find anything related in the JavaFX doc...
Thank you for the suggestions, they sound like good workarounds.

If you could please post references/simplified code chunk for both, I would select your answer with great pleasure. :)
Thanks again.